React Table Row click annotation / popup for showing the selected row
I tried to show the popup message in the end of the clicked row, but it is showing popup by using unwanted height and width position i need to show it within the end of right side of the row.
i handled the data using the popup height and width and the current screen innerwidth and innerheight to show the popup within screen and not taking any more space to show the popup.
here i attached the code below:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IoIosCloseCircle } from "react-icons/io";
const TableComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.com" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jane Smith", email: "jane.smith@example.com" },
    { id: 3, name: "Bob Johnson", email: "bob.johnson@example.com" },
    { id: 4, name: "Alice Williams", email: "alice.williams@example.com" },
    { id: 5, name: "Charlie Brown", email: "charlie.brown@example.com" },
    { id: 6, name: "David Wilson", email: "david.wilson@example.com" },
    { id: 7, name: "Eve Davis", email: "eve.davis@example.com" },
    { id: 8, name: "Frank Miller", email: "frank.miller@example.com" },
    { id: 9, name: "Grace Lee", email: "grace.lee@example.com" },
    { id: 10, name: "Henry Taylor", email: "henry.taylor@example.com" },
  ];
  const [show, updateShow] = useState({
    popupShow: false,
    popupMessage: { name: null, email: null },
    position: { x: null, y: null },
  });
  const handlePopupPosition = (e, row) => {
    const rowElement = e.currentTarget;
    const rowRect = rowElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const popupData = document.getElementById("popup-wrapper");
    const height = popupData?.clientHeight;
    const width = popupData?.clientWidth;
    
    let popupX = rowRect.right + window.scrollX;
    let popupY = rowRect.top + window.scrollY;

    popupX = Math.min(window.innerWidth, popupX) - width;
    popupY = Math.min(window.innerHeight, popupY) - height;
    updateShow({
      popupShow: true,
      popupMessage: { name: row.name, email: row.email },
      position: { x: popupX, y: popupY },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table-component">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((row) => (
            <tr
              key={row.id}
              onClick={(e) => {
                handlePopupPosition(e, row);
              }}
            >
              <td>{row.id}</td>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>{row.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {show.popupShow && (
        <div
          className={`popup arrow-left `}
          style={{
            left: show.position.x,
            top: show.position.y,
            position: "relative",
          }}
          id="popup-wrapper"
        >
          <div className="popup-wrapper">
            <IoIosCloseCircle
              className="text-danger pointer"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => {
                updateShow({
                  popupShow: false,
                  popupMessage: { name: null, email: null },
                });
              }}
            />
            <p>
              {show.popupMessage.name}
              {show.popupMessage.email}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default TableComponent;


I need to show the popup within the end of the clicked row.
